# How to insert the output of a code into an xml tag placeholder (python)

Tags: python, xml

My goal now is to use the output of a code as data for building an xml. Here's an example:

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element, SubElement, tostring
x=9**2.
xmlTemplate="""
<features>
    <name>%(name)s</name>
    <age>int(age)</age>
    <dob>%(dob)s</dob>
</features>"""
data={'name':'Michael', 'age':='x','dob':'20/10/1925'}

print xmlTemplate%data

<features>
    <name>Michael</name>
    <age>=x</age>
    <dob>20/10/1925</dob>
</features>
```

You can see that instead of using the output of the variable 'x' as input in the xml buildup, it just used the letter x (string).

Any suggestions on how to insert the output of 'x' in the age placeholder? Thanks in advance.

Comment: your code has a syntax error. did you mean `'age':'x'`? those `=` are odd...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `str.format()` function, putting `{}`'s where you want dynamic content to be. In your example, it would be:

```
x=9**2

xmlTemplate="""
<features>
<name>{name}</name>
<age>{age}</age>
<dob>{dob}</dob>
</features>""".format(name='Michael', age=x, dob='20/10/1925')
```

Comment: thanks for your response. I got the following error message:NameError: name 'Michael' is not defined.

Comment: @Tiger1 sorry, I missed the quotes around that. I edited the answer to reflect the correct format.

Comment: the program has syntax error: there's an error in your program, invalid syntax. The curly bracket i suppose.

Comment: Hi @jknupp, I got the following error message: NameError: name 'x' is not defined...try and implement the solution before posting it.

Comment: The previous error was a copy/paste mistake. If you're honestly telling me that you're getting a message saying `x` is not defined, you didn't copy the code.

Don't just blindly look at the error message and go change code. Think about what it is saying. Is there any possible way in the code above that `x` is not defined? No.

Comment: thanks for the solution, its now working fine. Its like I didn't copy the correct thing the first time.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple typos.... first, `%int(age)` isn't valid. You want `%(age)d`. Then, in your data, you have `age:'x'` (i think?) with the `'x'` in quotes. You just want the variable, so it should just be `x`. Then it looks like this:

```
x = 9**2

xmlTemplate="""
<features>
    <name>%(name)s</name>
    <age>%(age)d</age>
    <dob>%(dob)s</dob>
</features>"""
data={'name':'Michael', 'age':x,'dob':'20/10/1925'}

print xmlTemplate%data
```

The `format` method from the other example is also a good way to do it (and you can also call it as `xmlTemplate.format(**data)` if you use that), as the way you are using the old-style method is unusual, but perfectly valid and works fine if you fix those typos...

Comment: thanks for the solution and the brief but good explanation. The output is exactly what I wanted.